# Rename files to remove text after dot

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

I have these files:

```
JE.TR21201610011612514806.47250728
JE.TR21201610011613514807.91514463
JE.TR21201610011614514808.4107721050
JE.TR21201610011626514818.3578493139
JE.TR21201610011627514819.1032212591
JE.TR21201610011628514820.3663420052
JE.TR21201610011629514821.3388683091
```

How can I rename them to this?

```
JE.TR21201610011612514806
JE.TR21201610011613514807
JE.TR21201610011614514808
JE.TR21201610011624514817
JE.TR21201610011626514818
JE.TR21201610011627514819
JE.TR21201610011628514820
JE.TR21201610011629514821
```

Comment: for i in *; mv $i ${1:1:21} so some such - see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 8):

Any of

```
$ rename -n 's/\.\d*$//' JE.*
rename(JE.TR21201610011612514806.47250728, JE.TR21201610011612514806)
rename(JE.TR21201610011613514807.91514463, JE.TR21201610011613514807)
rename(JE.TR21201610011614514808.4107721050, JE.TR21201610011614514808)
rename(JE.TR21201610011626514818.3578493139, JE.TR21201610011626514818)
rename(JE.TR21201610011627514819.1032212591, JE.TR21201610011627514819)
rename(JE.TR21201610011628514820.3663420052, JE.TR21201610011628514820)
rename(JE.TR21201610011629514821.3388683091, JE.TR21201610011629514821)
```

or

```
$ prename -n 's/\.\d*$//' JE.*
JE.TR21201610011612514806.47250728 renamed as JE.TR21201610011612514806
JE.TR21201610011613514807.91514463 renamed as JE.TR21201610011613514807
JE.TR21201610011614514808.4107721050 renamed as JE.TR21201610011614514808
JE.TR21201610011626514818.3578493139 renamed as JE.TR21201610011626514818
JE.TR21201610011627514819.1032212591 renamed as JE.TR21201610011627514819
JE.TR21201610011628514820.3663420052 renamed as JE.TR21201610011628514820
JE.TR21201610011629514821.3388683091 renamed as JE.TR21201610011629514821
```

or

```
$ mmv -n "JE.*.*" JE.#1
JE.TR21201610011612514806.47250728 -> JE.TR21201610011612514806
JE.TR21201610011613514807.91514463 -> JE.TR21201610011613514807
JE.TR21201610011614514808.4107721050 -> JE.TR21201610011614514808
JE.TR21201610011626514818.3578493139 -> JE.TR21201610011626514818
JE.TR21201610011627514819.1032212591 -> JE.TR21201610011627514819
JE.TR21201610011628514820.3663420052 -> JE.TR21201610011628514820
JE.TR21201610011629514821.3388683091 -> JE.TR21201610011629514821
```

(remove the `-n` to complete the action)

or

```
$ for f in JE.*; do echo mv "$f" "${f%.*([0-9])}"; done
mv JE.TR21201610011612514806.47250728 JE.TR21201610011612514806
mv JE.TR21201610011613514807.91514463 JE.TR21201610011613514807
mv JE.TR21201610011614514808.4107721050 JE.TR21201610011614514808
mv JE.TR21201610011626514818.3578493139 JE.TR21201610011626514818
mv JE.TR21201610011627514819.1032212591 JE.TR21201610011627514819
mv JE.TR21201610011628514820.3663420052 JE.TR21201610011628514820
mv JE.TR21201610011629514821.3388683091 JE.TR21201610011629514821
```

(remove the `echo` to complete the action).

Comment: Or use `zsh` and `zmv '(JE.*).*' \$1`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to do it in Python:

```
$ tree
.
├── JE.TR21201610011612514806.47250728
├── JE.TR21201610011613514807.91514463
├── JE.TR21201610011614514808.4107721050
├── JE.TR21201610011626514818.3578493139
├── JE.TR21201610011627514819.1032212591
├── JE.TR21201610011628514820.3663420052
└── JE.TR21201610011629514821.3388683091

0 directories, 7 files
$ python -c 'import os,sys; map(lambda x: os.rename(x,x[0:x.rfind(".")]) , sys.argv[1:])' JE.*  
$ tree
.
├── JE.TR21201610011612514806
├── JE.TR21201610011613514807
├── JE.TR21201610011614514808
├── JE.TR21201610011626514818
├── JE.TR21201610011627514819
├── JE.TR21201610011628514820
└── JE.TR21201610011629514821
```

There's couple key points on how this works:

- we pass all filenames via `JE.*` glob, and then refer to them via `sys.argv[1:]`.
- `map()` allows us to perform the `lambda` function on whatever is in the `sys.argv[1:]` list slice.
- the `lambda` function that we have here makes use of `os.rename(old,new)` function to actually rename each item in the list
- `x[0:x.rfind(".")]` is actually a slice ( or substring ). Using the `.rfind()` function we find the index of the first occurrence of `.` starting from the right side of the string ( i.e. from the end ). Thus the list slice can be read as `x[0:<index of the last dot>]`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to rename files and folders is with the `mv` command (shortened from "move"). Its primary purpose is moving files and folders, but it can also rename them since the act of renaming a file is interpreted by the file system as moving it from one name to another.

The syntax is:

```
mv (option) file1.ext file2.ext
```

where `file1.ext` is the "old" name of the file, and `file2.ext` the new name.

Answer (score 0):

One command I use quite often is: `vidir`. `vi` or `vim` is for files and `vidir` is for directories.

If you execute vidir and get **command not found** you need to install the package **moreutils**:

`sudo apt-get install moreutils`

Back to your case:

1. Go to directory were the files are: `cd path-to-files`
2. Type command: `vidir` and press ENTER
3. Now you will see all list with all files, type this command: `:1,$ s/\.\d*$//g` (it searches for a dot followed by digits and removes everything to the end)
4. To exit and save type: `:x`

See also http://vimregex.com/